# Why is this simpler implementation of Java graphics not used?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I've been reading up on Java graphics, and all guides seem to point to more complicated implementations of graphics into Java; reading a bit about repaint(), I came up with this portion of code, which seems to work for the little that I have tested it with -

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Boids extends JFrame{

     public Boids(){
        setSize(400,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);   
     }

     public static void main(String[] a){
        Boids boids = new Boids();
        while(true) {
            boids.repaint();
        }
     }

     public void paint(Graphics g){
        // The code for Boids
     }
}
```

My question is; is this code bad in some way? Is it going to hurt me down the road?
If not, why is this not used, as it seems much simpler and shorter than other versions of code I have seen.

Comment: The short answers are "yes", "yes" and "because it is broken ... in lots of ways".  The "complexity" you see is there for good reason.  The fact that those reasons are not apparent to you means that you need to learn a lot more about how Java graphics works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Your comments suggest that you may have program logic within the `paint(...)` method, and this is something that should never be done since you don't have full control over when or if this will be called.
- Your code as written has no timing control over the animation loop.
- Your code risks running afoul of Swing threading rules.
- You are drawing directly in the JFrame, something that also should be strenuously avoided since this risks messing up with many of JFrame's responsibilities. Instead draw in a JComponent or JPanel's paintComponent method.

I can't remember who said this, maybe H.L. Menken, but it's something like, "for every complex problem there is a solution that is clear, simple, and wrong."

Comment: how does he have no control over if/when the paint is called?